# DNA Sequencing Error Probability Calculation

Tags: probability, statistics

I have some DNA sequencing data, and I am trying to calculate the probability of a base being erroneous or correct. I have drawn the question below to help clarify the question.

So, imagine have have 5 aligned reads at a given region of DNA. This is saying that a sequencer found five strands of DNA that all correspond to the same region of the genome. With a perfect sequencer, all reads would be identical sequences, but due to inherent error rates, mistakes will be made.

Let's only focus on the first letter of the sequence. In 4/5 reads 'A' was called by the sequencer, but in one of the reads the sequencer called a 'T'. Say we have a known sequencer error rate of 10% such that 1/10 bases called will be incorrect.

I would like to calculate the probability that I would be correct in calling 'A' the correct base at this location as I vary the number of aligned reads, the frequency of errors found, and error rate. So if I have 5 reads, how many 'T' calls could be made for me to be 95 or 99 percent sure that the correct base is an 'A'. Then, what if I have 10 reads or 100 etc...

[image: Illustration of question]

Comment: Do you happen to know what the typical error rate is in commercial DNA services (23andMe, etc.)? I tested several times; there were raw data differences in the results each time (as I recall, 50 SNPs or so were called differently between any 2 tests--this doesn't include no-calls). I also looked at several comparisons between parents and children; a number of SNPs were called in a way that was incompatible with Mendelian inheritance. There weren't many of these discrepancies, but the rate was significantly higher than the published human mutation rate, so I suspect they are due to test errors.

Comment: @MitchellSpector I don't really know because I've never looked at the data from companies like 23andMe. But sequencer error rates will be relatively uniform if done on the same platform. If 23andMe uses Illumina sequencing base substitution rates can be as high as 0.07 subs/base. But if they are missing SNPs they are falling prey to other problems as well.

Comment: You can model it as binomial distribution of n trials with k success for probability p, and solve for desired confidence level.

Comment: @karakfa Do you mind giving me an example or point me somewher?